# Symfony - "spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given"

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.4

I have a problem with the photo upload on a form. I can save my form with Doctrine into SQL, but when I want to save multiples images this error message appears :

> ContextErrorException HTTP 500 Internal Server Error Warning:
>   spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given

**PARENT : WebApp.php**

```
<?php

namespace MO\WebAppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
//pour le slug
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;


/**
 * WebApp
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="mo_travel")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MO\WebAppBundle\Repository\WebAppRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 *
 *
 */
class WebApp
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime")
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="author", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $author;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text")
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="published", type="boolean")
     */
    private $published = true;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="MO\WebAppBundle\Entity\Image", cascade={"persist"}, mappedBy="webapp"))
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="mo_travel_image")
     */
    private $image;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MO\WebAppBundle\Entity\Category", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="mo_travel_category")
     */
    private $categories;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"title"})
     * @ORM\Column(name="slug", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $slug;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * WebApp constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        // Par défaut, la date de l'annonce est la date d'aujourd'hui
        $this->date = new \Datetime();
        $this->categories = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->image = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function updateDate()
    {
        $this->setUpdatedAt(new \Datetime());
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set date
     *
     * @param \DateTime $date
     *
     * @return WebApp
     */
    public function setDate($date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get date
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDate()
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     *
     * @return WebApp
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set author
     *
     * @param string $author
     *
     * @return WebApp
     */
    public function setAuthor($author)
    {
        $this->author = $author;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get author
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthor()
    {
        return $this->author;
    }

    /**
     * Set content
     *
     * @param string $content
     *
     * @return WebApp
     */
    public function setContent($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get content
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    /**
     * @param boolean $published
     *
     * @return WebApp
     */
    public function setPublished($published)
    {
        $this->published = $published;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPublished()
    {
        return $this->published;
    }

    public function setImage(Image $image = null)
    {
        $this->image = $image;
    }

    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    /**
     * Add category
     *
     * @param \MO\WebAppBundle\Entity\Category $category
     *
     * @return WebApp
     */
    public function addCategory(\MO\WebAppBundle\Entity\Category $category)
    {
        $this->categories[] = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove category
     *
     * @param \MO\WebAppBundle\Entity\Category $category
     */
    public function removeCategory(\MO\WebAppBundle\Entity\Category $category)
    {
        $this->categories->removeElement($category);
    }

    /**
     * Get categories
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getCategories()
    {
        return $this->categories;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUpdatedAt()
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $updatedAt
     *
     * @return WebApp
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt($updatedAt)
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set slug
     *
     * @param string $slug
     *
     * @return WebApp
     */
    public function setSlug($slug)
    {
        $this->slug = $slug;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get slug
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSlug()
    {
        return $this->slug;
    }

}
```

**CHILDREN : Image.php**

```
<?php

namespace MO\WebAppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="mo_image")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Image
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="url", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $url;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="alt", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $alt;

    /**
     * @var UploadedFile
     */
    private $file;

    // On ajoute cet attribut pour y stocker le nom du fichier temporairement
    private $tempFilename;

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUpload()
    {
        // Si jamais il n'y a pas de fichier (champ facultatif), on ne fait rien
        if (null === $this->file) {
            return;
        }

        // Le nom du fichier est son id, on doit juste stocker également son extension
        // Pour faire propre, on devrait renommer cet attribut en « extension », plutôt que « url »
        $this->url = $this->file->guessExtension();

        // Et on génère l'attribut alt de la balise <img>, à la valeur du nom du fichier sur le PC de l'internaute
        $this->alt = $this->file->getClientOriginalName();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostPersist()
     * @ORM\PostUpdate()
     */
    public function upload()
    {
        // Si jamais il n'y a pas de fichier (champ facultatif), on ne fait rien
        if (null === $this->file) {
            return;
        }

        // Si on avait un ancien fichier (attribut tempFilename non null), on le supprime
        if (null !== $this->tempFilename) {
            $oldFile = $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->id.'.'.$this->tempFilename;
            if (file_exists($oldFile)) {
                unlink($oldFile);
            }
        }

        // On déplace le fichier envoyé dans le répertoire de notre choix
        $this->file->move(
            $this->getUploadRootDir(), // Le répertoire de destination
            $this->id.'.'.$this->url   // Le nom du fichier à créer, ici « id.extension »
        );
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreRemove()
     */
    public function preRemoveUpload()
    {
        // On sauvegarde temporairement le nom du fichier, car il dépend de l'id
        $this->tempFilename = $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->id.'.'.$this->url;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostRemove()
     */
    public function removeUpload()
    {
        // En PostRemove, on n'a pas accès à l'id, on utilise notre nom sauvegardé
        if (file_exists($this->tempFilename)) {
            // On supprime le fichier
            unlink($this->tempFilename);
        }
    }

    public function getUploadDir()
    {
        // On retourne le chemin relatif vers l'image pour un navigateur (relatif au répertoire /web donc)
        return 'uploads/img';
    }

    protected function getUploadRootDir()
    {
        // On retourne le chemin relatif vers l'image pour notre code PHP
        return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
    }

    public function getWebPath()
    {
        return $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->getId().'.'.$this->getUrl();
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $url
     */
    public function setUrl($url)
    {
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUrl()
    {
        return $this->url;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $alt
     */
    public function setAlt($alt)
    {
        $this->alt = $alt;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAlt()
    {
        return $this->alt;
    }

    /**
     * @return UploadedFile
     */
    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }

    /**
     * @param UploadedFile $file
     */
    // On modifie le setter de File, pour prendre en compte l'upload d'un fichier lorsqu'il en existe déjà un autre
    public function setFile(UploadedFile $file)
    {
        $this->file = $file;

        // On vérifie si on avait déjà un fichier pour cette entité
        if (null !== $this->url) {
            // On sauvegarde l'extension du fichier pour le supprimer plus tard
            $this->tempFilename = $this->url;

            // On réinitialise les valeurs des attributs url et alt
            $this->url = null;
            $this->alt = null;
        }
    }
}
```

**WebAppType.php**

```
<?php
namespace MO\WebAppBundle\Form;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateTimeType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
class WebAppType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * Réutilisabilité de notre formulaire
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('date',      DateTimeType::class)
            ->add('title',     TextType::class)
            ->add('author',    TextType::class)
            ->add('content',   TextareaType::class)
            ->add('image',ImageType::class, array("data_class" => null))

             /*
              ** - 1er argument : nom du champ, ici « categories », car c'est le nom de l'attribut
              ** - 2e argument : type du champ, ici « CollectionType » qui est une liste de quelque chose
              ** - 3e argument : tableau d'options du champ
              */
            ->add('categories', EntityType::class, array(
                'class'        => 'MOWebAppBundle:Category',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'expanded'     => true,
                'multiple'     => true,
            ))
            ->add('save',      SubmitType::class);
        // On ajoute une fonction qui va écouter un évènement de formulaire
        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,    // 1er argument : L'évènement qui nous intéresse : ici, PRE_SET_DATA
            function(FormEvent $event) { // 2e argument : La fonction à exécuter lorsque l'évènement est déclenché
                // On récupère notre objet WebApp (travel) sous-jacent
                $travel = $event->getData();
                // Cette condition est importante, on en reparle plus loin
                if (null === $travel) {
                    return; // On sort de la fonction sans rien faire lorsque $advert vaut null
                }
                // Si l'annonce n'est pas publiée, ou si id null
                if (!$travel->getPublished() || null === $travel->getId()) {
                    // Alors on ajoute le champ published
                    $event->getForm()->add('published', CheckboxType::class, array('required' => false));
                } else {
                    // Sinon, on le supprime
                    $event->getForm()->remove('published');
                }
            }
        );
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'MO\WebAppBundle\Entity\WebApp'
        ));
    }
}
```

**ImageType.php**

```
<?php

namespace MO\WebAppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ImageType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('file', FileType::class, array(
                'multiple'     => true ))
            ->add('url', TextType::class)
            ->add('alt', TextType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'MO\WebAppBundle\Entity\Image'
        ));
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for your responses.

Comment: Where is you controller?
And why the upload process is located inside your Entity?
For your question, the error said it: the function is expecting an object and you sent an array to it (the function it self is supposed to create a hash id for an object)
You also need to check the stacktrace to find the exact line of code causing that error